# php: simple_html_parse_DOM

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am using Laravel as framework and the class simple_html_parse_DOM to parse a website .
The problem is the foreach didn't work .It just parse the first element.

I want to parse the elements  in  every  tr :
example of the page i want to parse:

```
<tr>
    <td class="allf"><a href="cotation.aspx?s=ADWYA">ADWYA</a></td>
    <td>8.85</td>
    <td>9.02</td>
    <td>8.84</td>
    <td>3256</td>
    <td>29369</td>
    <td><b>9.02</b></td>
    <td><span class="quote_up2">0.00%</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="allf"><a href="cotation.aspx?s=AETEC">AETECH</a></td>
    <td>1.19</td>
    <td>1.19</td>
    <td>1.19</td>
    <td>1193</td>
    <td>1420</td>
    <td><b>1.19</b></td>
    <td><span class="quote_up2">0.00%</span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="allf"><a href="cotation.aspx?s=AL">AIR LIQUIDE TUNISIE</a></td>
    <td>147.00</td>
    <td>147.00</td>
    <td>147.00</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>882</td>
    <td><b>147.00</b></td>
    <td><span class="quote_up2">0.00%</span></td>
```

my code:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file('http://www.ilboursa.com/marches/aaz.aspx');
    $e = $html->find('#tabQuotes',0)->find('.alri');
$i=0;
    foreach ($e as $alri) :



      $Nom = $alri->children($i)->children(0)->plaintext;   
      $Ouverture = $alri->children($i)->children(1)->plaintext;    
      $Haut=$alri->children($i)->children(2)->plaintext;   
      $Bas=$alri->children($i)->children(3)->plaintext;    
      $Volumetitre =$alri->children($i)->children(4)->plaintext;    
      $Volumedt=$alri->children($i)->children(5)->plaintext;   
      $Dernier =$alri->children($i)->children(6)->plaintext;    
      $Variation=$alri->children($i)->children(7)->plaintext;    

        $cours = \App\Cours::create(array(
           'Nom'=>$Nom,
           'Ouverture'=>$Ouverture,
           'Haut'=>$Haut,
           'Bas'=>$Bas,
           'Volumetitre' =>$Volumetitre,
           'Volumedt'=>$Volumedt,
           'Dernier'=>$Dernier,
           'Variation' =>$Variation

        ));

         $i++;
 endforeach;
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: show us your foreach loop

Comment: my code:$html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load_file('http://www.ilboursa.com/marches/aaz.aspx');
  $e = $html->find('#tabQuotes',0)->find('.alri');
    $i=0;

Comment: foreach ($e as $alri) :
$Nom = $alri->children($i)->children(0)->plaintext;   
          $Ouverture = $alri->children($i)->children(1)->plaintext;    
          $Haut=$alri->children($i)->children(2)->plaintext;   
          $Bas=$alri->children($i)->children(3)->plaintext;    
          $Volumetitre =$alri->children($i)->children(4)->plaintext;    
          $Volumedt=$alri->children($i)->children(5)->plaintext;   
          $Dernier =$alri->children($i)->children(6)->plaintext;    
          $Variation=$alri->children($i)->children(7)->plaintext;    
$i++;

Comment: You should add the code to your question instead of in the comments. :)

Comment: Show us by EDITING your question, thx.

Comment: you have `<td class="allf">` but find `alli`

Comment: the classe Cours have this  proprieties: nom,Ouverture,Haut ....).The table  that contains this elements has alri as classe.What i wanna do is for every row is the table i instantiate a Cours

Comment: Does it mean that $e is list of tables?

Comment: yees and if i try to get just the first table (because there is just one) by adding a 0 to find ($html->find('#tabQuotes',0)->find('.alri',0);) i get an error :Call to a member function children() on integer

Comment: such code https://eval.in/581423 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$e = $html->find('#tabQuotes',0)->find('.alri');
// For every table 
foreach ($e as $alri) 
    // For every tr
    foreach($alri->find('tr') as $tr) { 
         // array of td
         $tds = $tr->find('td');

         $Nom = $tds[0]->plaintext;   
         $Ouverture = $tds[1]->plaintext;    
         $Haut = $tds[2]->plaintext;   
         $Bas = $tds[3]->plaintext;    
         $Volumetitre = $tds[4]->plaintext;    
         $Volumedt = $tds[5]->plaintext;   
         $Dernier = $tds[6]->plaintext;    
         $Variation = $tds[7]->plaintext;    

         $cours = \App\Cours::create(array(
           'Nom'=>$Nom,
           'Ouverture'=>$Ouverture,
           'Haut'=>$Haut,
           'Bas'=>$Bas,
           'Volumetitre' =>$Volumetitre,
           'Volumedt'=>$Volumedt,
           'Dernier'=>$Dernier,
           'Variation' =>$Variation
           ));
    }
```